Retrieve user join events across all groups on an account
I'm looking for a way of getting any user join events in any group the bot is connected to - using MTProto. There's not a dedicated handler/update for it to solve such scenario.
It doesn't look like there's a specific handler for it, so most likely on_raw_update() is the way to go. And I can indeed see updates when such joins occur - of type UpdateChatParticipants. The update looks like this:
{
    "_": "types.UpdateChatParticipants",
    "participants": {
        "_": "types.ChatParticipants",
        "chat_id": xx,
        "participants": [
            {
                "_": "types.ChatParticipant",
                "user_id": xx,
                "inviter_id": xx,
                "date": xx
            },
            {
                "_": "types.ChatParticipant",
                "user_id": xx,
                "inviter_id": xx,
                "date": xx
            },
            {
                "_": "types.ChatParticipantCreator",
                "user_id": xx
            }
        ],
        "version": 11
    }
}

But it looks like participants contains all members, not just the joined ones. Also, I'm not sure how to identify the user who actually joined from the list of all users.
The type description at https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/types/update-chat-participants doesn't help really. It's a list of https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/base/chat-participants#pyrogram.raw.base.ChatParticipants, which makes sense but also doesn't help much.
Hoping someone else having a clever idea. Thanks!
